# Normalizer in cloudconnect for Gooddata

Tags: gooddata

I have some doubts. I'm doing a BI for my company, and I needed to develop a data converter in ETL because the database to which it's connected (PostgreSQL) is bringing me some negative values within the time CSV. It doesn't make much sense to bring from the database (to which we don't have many accesses) negative data like this:

[image: data]

The solution I found so that I don't need to rely exclusively on dealing directly with the database would be to perform a conversion within the cloudconnect. I verified in my researches that the one that most contemplates would be the normalizer, but there are not many explanations available. Could you give me a hand? because I couldn't parameterize how I could convert this data from 00:00:-50 to 00:00:50 with the normalizer.

[image: Cloudconnect]

[image: normalizer]

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to review our CC documentation: https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/normalizer.html

However, I am not sure if normalizer would be able to process timestamps.
Normalizer is basically a generic transform component with a normalization template. You might as well use reformat component that is more universal.

However, what you are trying to do would require some very custom transform script, written in CTL (CloudConnect transformation language) or java.
You can find some templates and examples in the documentation: https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/ctl-templates-for-transformers.html

Comment: hey my friend,

Thanks for the guidelines, I will consider using reformat for such a demand. However as you said, possibly I will have to program something more in depth, can you tell me if there is any course available for CTL programming, I found little how to learn such programming or if it is just java.